# Get line numbers for Mono native crash

Tags: mono

I'm getting below stacktrace for a crash in Mono 4.4.1 runtime on CentOS.
Mono was built from tarball using configure, make, make install.
Is there some way to get more information about the line numbers being executed, such as enabling a flag in configure step?

```
    Native stacktrace:

    mono() [0x4ac038]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf100) [0x7efc4ff11100]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7efc4f95f5f7]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7efc4f960ce8]
    mono() [0x63e96e]
    mono() [0x63e75b]
    mono() [0x63e8bc]
    mono() [0x636332]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dc5) [0x7efc4ff09dc5]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7efc4fa20ced]

    Debug info from gdb:
    Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
    used by your application.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have gdb installed to be able to get line numbers in the output of the stack trace, like below.

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f0b023d8780 (LWP 9762)):
#0  0x00007f0b018a9ca9 in waitpid () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000004ac0fe in mono_handle_native_sigsegv (signal=signal@entry=11, ctx=ctx@entry=0x7f0b02337ac0, info=info@entry=0x7f0b02337bf0) at mini-exceptions.c:2348
#2  0x00000000004ff87e in mono_arch_handle_altstack_exception (sigctx=sigctx@entry=0x7f0b02337ac0, siginfo=siginfo@entry=0x7f0b02337bf0, fault_addr=<optimized out>, stack_ovf=stack_ovf@entry=0) at exceptions-amd64.c:808
#3  0x0000000000424832 in mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (_dummy=11, _info=0x7f0b02337bf0, context=0x7f0b02337ac0) at mini-runtime.c:2888
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x00007f0b018a66d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x000000000060d56b in mono_os_cond_wait (mutex=0x1594b70, cond=0x1594b98) at ../../mono/utils/mono-os-mutex.h:105
#7  mono_os_cond_timedwait (timeout_ms=4294967295, mutex=0x1594b70, cond=0x1594b98) at ../../mono/utils/mono-os-mutex.h:120
#8  _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (handle=handle@entry=0x40b, timeout=timeout@entry=4294967295, alertable=alertable@entry=1, poll=poll@entry=0, alerted=alerted@entry=0x7ffdbc5d208c) at handles.c:1554
#9  0x0000000000622992 in wapi_WaitForSingleObjectEx (handle=0x40b, timeout=timeout@entry=4294967295, alertable=alertable@entry=1) at wait.c:181
#10 0x000000000058eaa0 in mono_wait_uninterrupted (multiple=multiple@entry=0, numhandles=numhandles@entry=1, handles=handles@entry=0x7ffdbc5d2138, waitall=waitall@entry=0, ms=ms@entry=-1, thread=<optimized out>, alertable=1) at threads.c:1518
#11 0x00000000005903d5 in ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal (this_obj=<optimized out>, handle=0x40b, ms=-1, exitContext=<optimized out>) at threads.c:1652
```